# Facing Null-Pointer error on message source

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, junit5, spring-test

**this is my juntt 5 controller test cases class**

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(DomainController.class)
class DomainControllerTest {
  @Autowired private MockMvc mockMvc;
  @MockBean private DomainHandler domainHandler;


  @Test
  void save() throws Exception {
    when(domainHandler.save(any(DomainRequest.class))).thenReturn(createBaseResponseForSave());

    final var requestBuilder =
        post("/api/domain")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(DomainTestData.saveRequestJson());

    mockMvc
        .perform(requestBuilder)
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().json(DomainTestData.saveResponseJson()))
        .andReturn();
  }
}
```

**this is my data creation class**

```
public class DomainTestData {

  public static Domain domain = createDomain();
  public static final List<Domain> domainList = createDomainList();

  private static MessageSource messageSource;

  public static String getMessage(String key) {
    return messageSource.getMessage(key, null, Locale.getDefault());
  }

  public static BaseResponse createBaseResponseForSave() {
    String successMessage = getMessage("api.success.response");
    return new BaseResponse<>(
            1001,
        successMessage,
            new DomainResponse("Java", "bb11f2a9-a38a-45f5-92a2-3dbcefe8cb04")
    );
  }

  public static String convertObjectToFormattedJson(Object dataObject)
      throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(dataObject);
  }

  public static String saveResponseJson() throws JsonProcessingException {
    return convertObjectToFormattedJson(createBaseResponseForSave());
  }
}
```

**this is my MessageSource Configration class in**

```
exam-engine-core/src/main/java/com/testiqo/exam/engine/config/MessagePropertiesConfiguration.java
```

```
@Configuration
public class MessagePropertiesConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource =
        new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames(
        "classpath:/messages/api_error_messages",
        "classpath:/messages/api_response_messages",
        "classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return bean;
  }
}
```

**this is my api_response_messages.properties file in**

```
exam-engine-core/src/main/resources/messages/api_response_messages.properties
```

```
api.success.response=Success
api.successfully.saved.response={0} : {1} is saved successfully
api.successfully.updated.response={0} : {1} is updated successfully
api.successfully.deleted.response={0} is deleted successfully
api.not.found={0} not found
api.no.data.found=No data found for {0}
api.no.data.found.for.uid=No {0} found for given uid {1}
api.no.data.found.for.given.search.criteria=No data found for given search criteria
api.question.successfully.added.exam.response = Question successfully added in exam
api.exam.result.fetch = The exam result has been successfully fetched.
api.question.successfully.removed.exam.response = The question has been successfully removed from the exam
api.exam.view.response = The exam details have been fetched successfully
exam.not.found= {0} details not found for {1}
domain.not.found= {0} details not found for {1}
question.domain.not.found = Topic does not exist in domain
```

**when i run my test cases facing null-pointer error on MessageSource**

**This is my error**

```
Cannot invoke "org.springframework.context.MessageSource.getMessage(String, Object[], java.util.Locale)" because "com.testiqo.exam.engine.utils.domain.DomainTestData.messageSource" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.context.MessageSource.getMessage(String, Object[], java.util.Locale)" because "com.testiqo.exam.engine.utils.domain.DomainTestData.messageSource" is null
    at com.testiqo.exam.engine.utils.domain.DomainTestData.getMessage(DomainTestData.java:29)
    at com.testiqo.exam.engine.utils.domain.DomainTestData.createBaseResponseForSave(DomainTestData.java:33)
    at com.testiqo.exam.engine.controller.DomainControllerTest.save(DomainControllerTest.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
```

**I need to use MessageSource for get message so how to use MessageSource**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supposed, you've got this NPE because the class `DomainControllerTest` calls the static method `createBaseResponseForSave()` from the class `DomainTestData` that use the static class member `messageSource`. The NPE occures because Spring cannot inject the bean `messageSource` into a static context.

To avoid the NPE, it's enough for you to just make the class `DomainTestData` non-static -> make class member `messageSource` non-static which will allow Spring to inject the bean `messageSource` through a constructor.

Also you can try to define the bean `messageSource` as a static bean and this can help too. But I'm not sure it will work.

**UPD**

Related changes:

The first change is to make the `DomainTestData` class non-static. To do this, youd need to remove the `static` special word in the line `private static MessageSource messageSource;` and do the same for two methods: `getMessage(...)` and `createBaseResponseForSave()`. The next step is to create a constructor for this class as follows:

```
public DomainTestData(MessageSource messageSource) {
    this.messageSourcec = messageSource;
}
```

The second change is to tell Spring to inject the `messageSource` bean into the `DomainTestData` class. To do this it's enough to add the `@Component` annotation above the class declaration as follows:

```
@Component
public class DomainTestData {
   // ...
}
```

And the final step is to inject the changed `DomainTestData` class into the `DomainControllerTest` and change the static method call of this class to a call via class-member as follows:

```
class DomainControllerTest {
    // ...
    @Autowired private DomainTestData domainTestData;
    // ...
    
    @Test
    void save() throws Exception {
         when(domainHandler.save(any(DomainRequest.class))).thenReturn(domainTestData.createBaseResponseForSave());
         // ...
    }
```

Comment: can you provide related changes? @MaksimEliseev

Comment: I updated my answer and added some related changes @AnupPanchal